# How to modify result of select statement based on values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grafana

I am not MySQL guy just learning by doing things, I have database that stores value 0 or 1, now in grafana I want to display online if value yield from select statement is 1 and offline if value of online in select statement is 0.

So far this is what I wrote

```
SELECT  "online" if online == 1 else "offline", datetime_added as time from roku_online_status order by id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But select statement through error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `case` expression:

```sql
SELECT   CASE online WHEN 1 THEN 'online' ELSE 'offline' END, datetime_added AS time
FROM     roku_online_status
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT if(online = 1, "online", "offline") as status, 
datetime_added as time 
from roku_online_status
 order by id 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```